# Angular2 ngIf not updating DOM?

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I can't seem to find the correct expression for ngIf to evaluate correctly.

I followed the simple [Angularfire2 example here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md), and it lets me log in and log out correctly.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div> {{ (af.auth | async)?.uid }} </div>
  <button (click)="login()">Login</button>
  <button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => console.log(auth));
  }

  login() {
    this.af.auth.login();
  }

  logout() {
     this.af.auth.logout();
  }
}
```

I want to modify the code to show/hide the correct buttons depending upon the logged in state. I can see in the console that auth is switching from null to object and back, but the DOM isn't updating.

Here is the latest attempt:

```
<div> {{ (af.auth | async)?.uid }} </div>
<button *ngIf="!(auth | async)" (click)="login()">Login</button>
<button *ngIf="auth | async" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this to evaluate correctly?

Comment: You cannot see **auth** parameter to the subscribe function from the html template. You had better create a boolean variable in the class, set it in the subscriber and refer it in the ngIf clause to hide/show buttons.

Comment: IS AUTH returning a boolean? What does console.log for auth say?

Comment: @deek auth is an object. The log shows "null" or a valid object with properties as the buttons are clicked.

Comment: @MeteCantimur Isn't the point of templates to be able to use class variables in them? Seems like overkill to put a boolean and track it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: You are not subscribing to the changed status of login in you `login` and `logout` methods, so you should add: `this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => this.auth = auth);` to the methods.

I'm not familiar with Angularfire, but ...  if the auth is switching from `null` and back, you can store and use that. Store it, e.g when you subscribe, you could subscribe `auth => this.auth = auth` instead of `console.log`, then you could just use it like so:

```
<button *ngIf="auth == null" (click)="login()">Login</button>
<button *ngIf="auth != null" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
```

Maybe this is not the best way. You could also create a boolean, like `isLogged` and use that to show/hide buttons.

And sure, there is probably be nicer way to do this... But at least an options here.

Comment: I also tried this way and it doesn't work. It should though right?

Comment: Yeah, it should. Just realized when looking at your code after a good night of sleep, do you subscribe to your changes anywhere when clicking button? I mean, you only subscribe in the constructor upon navigating to page... If you click login button when not logged in, you are not subscribing to the changed login status, so therefore button status won't change either. Or am I misunderstanding something here now?

Comment: I added a boolean and in the subscribe to auth I change it's value and it now works, and it similar to your solution (change a local based on subscription). @MeteCantimur had a similar suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look for [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html) and [safe navigation operator (?.)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) to understand `(af.auth | async)?.uid`  expression

```
template: `
<div [ngSwitch]="(af.auth | async)?.uid">
 <button *ngSwitchCase="null" (click)="login()">Login</button>
 <button *ngSwitchDefault (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
</div>`
```

Comment: Interesting idea to use ngSwitch, but the above doesn't work when auth is a valid object. Is "true" the right test for this?

Comment: if you replace `(af.auth | async)?.uid` with `(af.auth | async).uid` does it work?

Comment: No, still doesn't work. Thanks for the references to async and safe operator though. I went ahead and accepted AJT_82's answer for now. Cheers.

Comment: added switch default